# Endless wait(NULL) on C if I use exec function

Tags: linux, makefile, c

I am using C programming language, and gcc compiler of C 99 standard.
A program of mine is stuck during wait(NULL) of a parent process.
There are three programs I am using. All are using command-line arguments.

Because I am also using file-redirection:

1. Adding prints does not necessarily helps, because some prints are not printed from a certain
2. There is a feeling that some characters are corrupted.

The program of the parent process is called *foo*. It executes another program called *goo*, and *goo* executes a third program called *hoo*.

If I just execute goo, this works fine. I can provide test files for example that I get valid resulsts with them. This is weird, because I would have expect that goo would be in an endless run, what does not happen.

I am adding code in case this is not some fundamental issue. Currently my main issue is that wait() is stuck within *foo* and not the functionality!

**Foo.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Program use: there are m files. 
    // It needs to execute goo for each different file.
    int i = 0, output_fd = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (output_fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** open failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {
            int pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                char* arg_vec[3] = { "goo", argv[i], NULL };
                dup2(output_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                execve("goo", arg_vec, NULL); // Check why it's execution does not end?
                fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** execve failed!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else if (pid < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** fork failed!\n");
                return 1;
            }
    }

    while(wait(NULL) > 0)
    {
    }

    close(output_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**goo.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char** create_argv(char* student_details_line);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Program use: read a file of n lines, each lines consists details for n different students. 
    // For each student, a fork() called, and then executes hoo program.
    
    char* student_details_line = NULL;
    size_t len;
    int num_stud = 0, input_fd = open("hoo", stdin), output_fd = open(file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (input_fd < 0 || output_fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** file descriptor failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Reading input from stdin
    FILE* input_file = fdopen(input_fd, "r");
    if (input_file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening input file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (getline(&student_details_line, &len, input_file) != -1)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            char** arg_vec = create_argv(student_details_line);
            dup2(input_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(output_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
            execve("hoo", arg_vec, NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** execve failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (pid < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** fork failed!\n");
            return -1;
        }
        else
            num_stud++;
    }
    while(wait(NULL) > 0)
    {
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    close(input_fd);
    close(output_fd);
    printf("There are %d students\n", num_stud);

    return 1;
}

char** create_argv(char* student_details_line)
{
    int pid = getpid(), size = 0, max_arguments = 2;

    char** arguments_arr = (char**)malloc(max_arguments * sizeof(char*));
    if (arguments_arr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** malloc failed!\n");
        _exit(1);
    }
    arguments_arr[size++] = strdup("hoo"); // Program name

    // Get the first token
    char* token = strtok(student_details_line, "\n\b\t ");
    arguments_arr[size++] = strdup(token);
    
    // Walk through other tokens
    while (1) 
    {
        // Reallocate array
        if (max_arguments == size)
        {
            max_arguments = max_arguments * 2;
            char** new_arguments_arr = (char**)realloc(arguments_arr, max_arguments * sizeof(char*));
            if (new_arguments_arr == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** realloc failed!\n");
                free(arguments_arr);
                _exit(1);
            }
            arguments_arr = new_arguments_arr;
        }
        // Get new token, add it to arguments vector and update the amount of arguments
        if ((token = strtok(NULL, "\n\b\t ")) != NULL)
            arguments_arr[size++] = strdup(token);
        // No more tokens
        else
            break;
    }
    
    // Reallocate array
    if (max_arguments == size)
    {
        max_arguments = max_arguments * 2;
        char** new_arguments_arr = (char**)realloc(arguments_arr, max_arguments * sizeof(char*));
        if (new_arguments_arr == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "*** ERROR: *** realloc failed!\n");
            free(arguments_arr);
            _exit(1);
        }
        arguments_arr = new_arguments_arr;
    }
    // Function's output
    return arguments_arr;
}
```

**hoo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Program use: returns a name of a student and his average grade in one-liner
    double average_grade = 0;
    int total_grades = 0;

    // Iterate over other arguments (grades only)
    for (int i = 2; 0 < argc && i < argc; i++)
    {
        char* end_ptr = NULL;
        int grade = strtol(argv[i], &end_ptr, 10);
        int ptr_size = strlen(end_ptr);
        for (int j = 0; j < ptr_size; j++)
        {
            if (14 <= end_ptr[j])
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Argument %s is non-integer\n", argv[i]);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        average_grade += grade;
        total_grades++;
    }
    // Prints student name and his average grade
    if (total_grades == 0)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s NaN\n", argv[1]);
    else
    {
        average_grade = average_grade / total_grades;
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %.1f\n", argv[1], average_grade);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
# Makefile for ex2_q1 spring 2023B

CFLAGS   = -Wall -std=c99
LDFLAGS  = -lm
CC       = gcc
ECHO     = @echo "going to build target $@ (dependent on $^)"

PROG1 = one_student
PROG2 = read_grades
PROG3 = ex2_q1
PROGS = $(PROG1) $(PROG2) $(PROG3)

all: $(PROGS) test


$(PROG1): $(PROG1).c $(PROG3).h
    $(ECHO)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

$(PROG2): $(PROG2).c $(PROG3).h
    $(ECHO)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

$(PROG3): $(PROG3).c $(PROG3).h
    $(ECHO)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -vf *.o ${PROG} all_std.log *.temp

test: $(PROGS)
    @echo going to run test...
    ./$(PROG3) readers_msg.txt gr_1.txt
```

**gr_1.txt**

```
Avi 80 90 75
Beni 90
Gadi 70 9 90 100
```

I am sorry for the amount of code lines. Really thankful for helpers...

Comment: what are the command lines for your foo, goo, hoo?
where is makefile?

Comment: @WhiteOwl I added the Makefile and the file mentioned within it (gr_1.txt). The command line for testing goo is "./read_grades < gr_1.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, `foo` is waiting endlessly because the various `goo` processes aren’t exiting: they’re stuck waiting for input. If you either change `foo` to redirect `goo`’s standard input to read from the file it’s supposed to process, or change `goo` to read from the file given in its arguments instead of its standard input, everything should work.

Comment: I now added input file redirection for ```goo```, but I get segmentation fault, according to chatGPT. I updated the code